# Century Link land line callers get busy signal when calling my Google Voice Number

Tags: google-voice

This started about 2 weeks ago, I have posted my problem to the Google Voice Forum with no response from anyone that can help. I know it's a free service, and you get what you pay for but I need it to work. I love Google voice and have had it since the beginning, but it's got to work.

How can I get the problem fixed. Is there a way to get Google to address this? Is there a better way to contact Google?

Comment: Are they dialing the area code? 1+area code? Same results from all options?

Comment: @Raystafarian They are all local numbers to me, so no area code required.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought GV always wants area codes and landlines don't automatically append it like mobile phones.

Comment: @Raystafarian Positive, had this number for years, this is a new problem, these numbers call me all the time. If you dial the area code with or without the one you get a recording telling you it's not necessary to dial one or the area code to complete this call. Remember this is incoming calls to my GV number, not me dialing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you keep posting in almost troll like fashion until you get the attention of one of the Top Contributors who will escalate it to a Google employee. That's what finally got the problem resolved.